# c code compiles but is not executed in kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu, compile

I'm running kubuntu 9.10 in VirtualBox, i wrote the simplest "hello world" program in C, the code compiles, i ran it through a debugger and it seems to run fine. the only problem is nothing gets actually printed to the console...
any ideas ?

heres the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

i compiled it using:

```
gcc -c test.c -o test.o
gcc test.o -o test
```

i get no error messages.

Comment: What commands do you use? and specifically to run it ?

Comment: are you getting any error mesages or is there absolutely nothing displayed??

Comment: Craigs answer is the correct one. Hoekstras answer works but does not explain why you got an error.

Comment: while this seems like a Stack Overflow question, it isn't really about the code, or the compiling, but about the execution (PATH).  it should stay on Super User.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your path has /usr/bin before .

Try running it as ./test

/usr/bin/test just exits with no output

Comment: +1 This is in my opinion the correct answer. I have been bitten by this problem myself. **NEVER** call your program test!

Comment: +1 As this is the real answer to the question, where i only answered it by accident.

Comment: Having `.` in your path at all is not common, so it's not really a matter it being "before". Invoking it with the path is the correct solution though.

Comment: It should be noted that `test` is a builtin in Bash and many other shells so it would be executed before `/usr/bin/test` (and `test` without specifying a directory or not in `PATH` or late in `PATH`).

Answer (score -1):

```
gcc -o helloWorld test.c
```

When compiling is done without errors

```
./helloWorld
```

And your program should run, displaying `hello world`

That should work fine.

**EDIT**
Even though this "works" the real answer is using ./ to run the executable in the current directory. Where else it would run /usr/bin/test. All credits to Craig :)

Comment: that worked! thanks :)
im sorry if its a stupid question but why wasn't it necessary to compile the source to an object file first in this case? furthermore, why does it cause a problem ?

Comment: You're welcome. 
In this case it's not necessary. You can compile simple code like this directly into one executable.
Object files are only used in more complex programs.

Comment: I don't think the problem was how you compiled but the name of the executable.  See my answer below.

Comment: You are probably right too, but it's not possible to execute an object file directly. That had to be fixed first.

Comment: He built an executable note the second gcc line -- gcc test.o -o test builds test from test.o

Comment: ah yes you're right. No clue how that slipped past me...

Comment: -1 You missed the point. He called his program `test` this program already exists in `/usr/bin/test` and this is the exe he runs when he just tryst to run `test` from the command line.